# How to Write Excel Function into Cell using a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, function, formula

Thanks for taking a look.
I am using VBA to populate cells where other code programatically finds the last empty row and writes into the cells. I have this part working fine. The variable for the row number is "lastrow"
The function is GetStuff() and has only one parameter, the cell address containing the data to be manipulated by the functionis in lastrow Col C. If I were to type it in, it might look like =GetStuff(C19). I don't use ".Value" because the function would execute immediately, a problem because a User will later enter the Col C data by typing it.
Here, the cell containing the data is in column C of the current row.
The relevant line of code is below, but doesn't work:

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Formula = "=GetStuff("C" & lastrow)"
```

I want to write the function into a cell in column D of the currently selected row for execution when the worksheet updates. "xlCalculationManual" is set for the moment. Help. I'm stuck.
Thank you.
-DL

This is what I have tried:

> ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Formula = "=GetStuff("C" & lastrow)"
> ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Formula = GetStuff("C" & lastrow)
> ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Formula = "=GetStuff("C" & lastrow)"
> ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, "D").Formula = "=GetStuff("C", "& lastrow")"

Comment: What happens if you change your original formula to: `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 4)...`?

Comment: Try `... = "=GetStuff(C" & lastrow & ")"`.

Comment: That seems to work. The cell content is now =@GetStuff(C21).
Not sure I understand the @ operator, but MS says the function will work.  
Thank you!

Comment: Use `.Formula2` to get rid of the `@`.